# how to do a count in RACKET

Tags: count, scheme, racket

i'm trying to write a code in RACKET , i know how to solve it but i'm having some trouble , i can use your help .

the function will get a list and a specific symbol , and it need to return the number of times that the symbol is shown in the list . 
in the test - i'm comparing the result with a number i'm asking and should return true if the number is the same .

i've tried to do it with (if / cond / and even tried acc ) - but there is always something that is missing .

here is my code including the test . 
please help me find out how to write it .

the idea of the solution is , the i take the head of the list and i check if it's equal to the symbol i wrote , if it does  - n is plus 1 , empty list is equal 0 .

```
( : counts : (Listof Symbol) -> Integer )    

(define (counts a n )  ; a = list of symbols.    
  (cond [(null? a) 0])    
    [(eq?(first a) 'x) (= n(+ n 1))]     
         (counts( (rest a) n)))    

;test:    
(test (eq? (counts ('a 'b 'x) )1))
```

Comment: Naming. If you need a comment to remind yourself what `a` is, why not simply pick a better, more readable name for it? Suggestion: `a-list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- The `cond` expression is being incorrectly used, and the `else` case is missing
- There are erroneous parentheses, for example at the end of the second line in `counts` and when you call `counts` in the fourth line
- In the base case of the recursion you must return `n`, the counter
- You must also call the recursion if the symbol was found, in the second case
- This part: `(= n (+ n 1))` is *not* doing what you think, it's *not* changing the value of `n`, instead is testing for equality between `n` and `(+ n 1)` (which will return false, of course)
- You're not passing as parameter the symbol being searched, it's hard-coded in the procedure

This is a corrected version of what you intended to write:

```
(define (counts a x n)
  (cond [(null? a) n]
        [(eq? (first a) x)
         (counts (rest a) x (+ n 1))]
        [else
         (counts (rest a) x n)]))
```

Use it like this:

```
(counts '(a b x c d x e x) 'x 0)
=> 3
```

I advice you to grab a good book or tutorial, it seems you're struggling with the basic syntax. And learn how to use DrRacket to help with the syntax errors, it's an excellent IDE.

Comment: thanks ! , but it's still not working , as i wrote i need to run a test with numbers and see if the number that i got with the function is equal to the number i wrote

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the fact that the symbol that's being searched is a parameter, not a hard-coded `'x` as it was before. Update your tests, the code above _works_, I just tested it.

Comment: Be clear about this: how many parameters you're supposed to pass to the procedure? what are they supposed to be? in the function definition, you mention only one: the list. In your implementation you use two: the list and the counter. In my implementation I have three: the list, the element being searched and the counter - because you mentioned that "the function will get a list and a specific symbol"

Comment: oh sorry about that , the function receive 2 , since the symbol 'x it hard coded in the function .

Comment: is it a tail recursive?

Comment: since n is my accumulator

Comment: @user3433101 Yes. It's tail recursive.